# Calculate size of an object inside a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the real size of a papersheet sticked to a panel whose I know the dimensions. Here is a little example : 
[image]

My program works fine when the picture is taken in front of the panel, I get 0.416 * 0.294 while my sheet's real size is 0.420 * 0.297 which is very satisfying. You can try my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/darzang/m7777w4k/).
And below is the function I made for the calculations

```
window.calculer = function(){


//-------------Calcul de X ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


ag_distance_x_metres=0.9;


ag_delta_x=x2-x1;                                                                       // Calcul des ag_delta_x et ag_delta_y 
ag_delta_y=y2-y1;


ag_distance_x_pixels=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ag_delta_x, 2) + Math.pow(ag_delta_y, 2));      // Calcul de la distance x en pixels


ag_rapport_x = ag_distance_x_pixels/ag_distance_x_metres;                               // Calcul du rapport taille pixel / taille mètres 


ag_delta_X = x5-x4;                                                                     // Calcul des ag_delta_X et ag_delta_Y 
ag_delta_Y = y5-y4;


ag_distance_X_pixels=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ag_delta_X, 2) + Math.pow(ag_delta_Y, 2));      // Calcul de la distance X en pixels


ag_distance_X_metres=ag_distance_X_pixels/ag_rapport_x;                                 // Calcul de la distance X en mètres
alert("ag_distance_X_metres = "+ ag_distance_X_metres);


//-------------Calcul de Y -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ag_distance_y_metres=1.20;


ag_delta_x=x3-x2;                                                                       // Calcul des ag_delta_x et ag_delta_y 
ag_delta_y=y3-y2;


ag_distance_y_pixels=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ag_delta_x, 2) + Math.pow(ag_delta_y, 2));      // Calcul de la distance y en pixels



ag_rapport_y = ag_distance_y_pixels/ag_distance_y_metres;                               // Calcul du rapport taille pixel / taille mètres 



ag_delta_X = x6-x5;                                                                     // Calcul des ag_delta_X et ag_delta_Y 
ag_delta_Y = y6-y5;


ag_distance_Y_pixels=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ag_delta_X, 2) + Math.pow(ag_delta_Y, 2));      // Calcul de la distance Y en pixels


ag_distance_Y_metres=ag_distance_Y_pixels/ag_rapport_y;                                 // Calcul de la distance Y en mètres
alert("ag_distance_Y_metres = "+ ag_distance_Y_metres);

}
```

Now I'm trying to do the exact same thing, but when the picture is not taken in front of the panel, like this one :
[image]
You can try the same code with this image [here](https://jsfiddle.net/darzang/n223js0k/1/)

With this image I get 0.405*0.254 for my sheet dimensions, which is not that far, but not good enough. I'd like to have something more accurate, but I don't know how to do it, I think I may have to take more parameters into account but I don't really know much about photography and I'm kinda lost here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit** : As there is isn't any answers, and i searched on google without success, I'm starting to think that I don't have enough datas to make such a calculation.
Now what if :

- I have the focal length and sensor size
- I have the distances between my camera and the points 1,2 and 3
- I have both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find the [vanishing points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point) of your perspective, and use it to compute the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) of the parallel lines. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216298/how-to-calculate-true-lengths-from-perspective-projection) for more details.

---

As it is said in the answer, your first example works because:

> If the vanishing point of a given line is at infinity, like for the horizontal
>   lines in your picture, then they are only subject to an affine
>   transformation, so ratios of lengths on these lines are preserved by
>   the perspective projection.

For your second example, you have to use the method given in the answer.

Let's consider that you have a coordinate system, with origin O (the side of the panel) and axis x (inverse of the direction of the vanishing point from O). A is the vanishing point, B, the other side of the panel, and C and D the intersection of axis x with the sheet.
[image: Coordinate system]

The cross-ratio `CR(A,O;B,C)` is `((A-B)/(A-C))/((O-B)/(O-C)) = 0.189`, with
`A = -317px` (distance from O to A in the resized picture), `B = 166`, `C = 22`, `D = 92.`
So, since you know that `OB = 90cm`, you have `OC = 0.189 * 90 = 17 cm`.
For `OD, CR(A,O;B,D) = 0.654`, so you have `OD = 0.654 * 90 = 58.9`.
Thus, `CD = OD - OC = 41.9 cm`.

You have to do the same for the other direction, following the blue lines.

If your sheet is not aligned with the panel direction, you just have to compute the coordinates of each corner in a coordinate system defined by the panel axes. The principle remains the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for everything !

Comment: Actually, i have a little question about the vanishing point. Do i take the borders of the sheet, or the borders of my panel to get the vanishing point ? I think it's the sheet's borders but I'm not quite sure about it :/

Comment: You need to take the borders of your reference, so the borders of the panel. In the case here the sheet and the panel are aligned, that's why we can do CD=OD-OC. But in a more general case, you have to find the coordinates of each corner of the sheet (x,y) in the panel reference system, and then compute the distance between the corners.

Comment: I corrected my code and it's better now, i have the right dimensions when i used my picture taken in front of the panel ( https://jsfiddle.net/darzang/4nav5a5o/ ) And from the image taken from the side ( the one you took in order to explain the calculations) but when i try with another image i got something weird. (https://jsfiddle.net/darzang/4nav5a5o/1/) If i try to get the dimensions of the A3 paper on top of the panel, i get the good width, but not the good height, and when i try with the A4 paper on the right, i get the opposite ( good height but bad width ).

Comment: Here is a direct link to the pictures since they are really crappy in jsfiddle : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=801464photodeface.jpg     http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=815557test2.jpg

Comment: Hmm, do you get a result very far from the expected one ? Can you detail your calculus ?

Comment: Okay I think I found my mistake. When my vanishing point A is on the right ( or B on the top ), my corresponding points O and Q were still placed like the point A was on the left, and B on the bottom. I'm currently trying to fix this and will keep you in touch

Comment: Problem solved, I adjusted my functions so that they check if the vanishings points are at the left or right for A , and at the top or bottom for B. It works well now, I tried it with a building and I got 10,786 meters while the real length is 10.82 meters, so that is clearly precise enough for what I need to do with it. Thanks again !

Comment: Great, glad it helped !